# How add drop-down arrow states in Bootstrap 4 accordion using Angular or CSS

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

How can I implement a simple arrow (>) to indicate the `aria-expanded="true" or aria-expanded="false"` states in the Bootstrap 4 accordion using either Angular2 or plain CSS?

I have watched a bunch of tutorials and tried even more, but I think I am missing something.

I have tried using CSS only, but the arrow does not display (this might be the way to go):

```
.card .card-header:after{
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #f07f09;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And I have tried using `ngClass`, but my issue is that it applies the arrow state to all elements with the below code (is there a way to use index to make this work?):

```
<i [ngClass]="{'right':!expanded, 'down':expanded}"></i>
```

and the method setting the state:

```
(click)="changeDropdownArrowState()"
```

Method in my component:

```
  changeDropdownArrowState () {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" (click)="changeDropdownArrowState()">
                <h1>Personal Details
                    <i [ngClass]="{'right':!expanded, 'down':expanded}"></i>
                </h1>
            </button>
        </h2>

    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#retailCliamAccordian">
        <div class="card-body">
            some text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" (click)="changeDropdownArrowState()">
                <h1>Product Details
                    <i [ngClass]="{'right':!expanded, 'down':expanded}"></i>
                </h1>
            </button>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#retailCliamAccordian">
        <div class="card-body">
            other text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
i {
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid #f07f09;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[image]

I think using the attribute `aria-expanded="true/false"` might be another way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "just want it to work", you can create an array of true/false values in `.ts` file like so:
`expandableAreasState = [true, false, false, ...] // in this example first item will be expanded by default`

and then redefine the method:

```
  changeDropdownArrowState(index: number) {
    this.expandableAreasState[index] = !this.expandableAreasState[index];
  }
```

and call inside template like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" (click)="changeDropdownArrowState(0)"> // next one with 1 instead of 0 and so on...
     <h1>Product Details
          <i [ngClass]="{'right':!expandableAreasState[0], 'down':expandableAreasState[0]}"></i>
     </h1>
</button>
```

However, I would probably go ahead and use ng-bootstrap in your case, since its introduces bootstrap without any jQuery dependencies and greately simplifies development with its set of directives.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

If your cards aren't too complex and different among themselves I would then consider creating an interface like so:

```
CardConfig {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  ...
}
```

and create an array of these card settings in some util / config file like so:

```
export const cardConfiguration: CardConfig[] = [{title: ''Personal details, text: 'some text', ...}]
```

which I would then import in the `component.ts`:

```
cardConfig = cardConfiguration
```

and loop over them with `*ngFor` inside template.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the detailed answer! Yeah, it is a quick and dirty, but works like a charm. After experiencing too many issues with ng-bootstrap, I dropped it. :)